# AJAX replace and scroll sideways

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, plugins, animation

I have been able to find plenty of ways to load and replace content with ajax and hide/show with an effect.

But I am looking for a way to slide the new content into a div while the old content slides out.

I guess this would require appending the loaded content after the already present content, but how do I align existing/loaded content horizontally and scroll within the div?

Any suggestions for good plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating sliding panel is relatively easy. First you create a container with a fixed width that will hide the overflow. Then you have a moving panel, with a large width of i.e. 5000px and inside content each contained in a div.

### HTML

```
<div id="container">

    <div id="panel">
        <div>Content 1</div>
        <div>Content 2</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

### CSS

```
#panel div {
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
    height: 350px;
}

#panel {
   width: 5000px;
}

#container {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 302px;
}
```

### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#panel').delay(2500).animate({
        marginLeft: '-=302px'
    }, 500);

});
```

We slide the left margin of the panel to a negative value, so it moves the whole panel to the left by the amount the width of the content to slide into view (in this case 302 pixels).

**Fiddle available:** http://jsfiddle.net/cMKbA/2/

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big fan of the Nivo Slider located here http://nivo.dev7studios.com.